# Looping through inner jquery accordion fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a way to create a loop for the  and  statements inside an jquery accordion , so I can iterate through my JSON.

The code below has the JSON working, so I want the data from the JSON to fill my jquery accordion.  Just don't know how to work around the h3 and div tags that teh accordion needs.

```
         <html>



<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/development-bundle/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.selectable.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/development-bundle/demos/demos.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
</script><script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
            $.getJSON(ReturnPlacesJSON.php, function(data) {
                /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(val.xcoord, val.ycoord);
                    var title = (val.title)?val.title:""
                    var icon = 'http://shanewmiller.com/Specials/images/beermug.png';
                    var special = val.Description;
                    var end = (val.endtime)?val.endtime:""
                    var start = (val.starttime)?val.starttime+" - ":""
                    var day = (val.day)?val.day:""
                    var html = val.name + val.address + special + day + start + end;

                    $('<h3 />').html(special).appendTo('#accordion');
                    $('<div />').html(val.name + ' ' + val.address).appendTo('#accordion');
                });
            });
        }); 

    </script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
    </div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: So your h3/divs are hardcoded in the html?

Comment: `.each()` expects a function, I am not sure what you are doing with the strings.

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: Can you also show your json that's returned?

Comment: The JSON is returning data from my SQL Server.  I just need it to fill into the accordion jquery function, so it creates a tab for each title I bring in with the body to go after.  And yes so they can hardcode the data in the html format.

Comment: [{"name":"The Cage","address":"401 Main St, Utica, NY","xcoord":"43.103705","ycoord":"-75.222728"},{"name":"The Celtic Harp","address":"805 Varick St, Utica, NY","xcoord":"43.103251","ycoord":"-75.243857"},{"name":"Piggy Pats","address":"3955 Edgebrook Place New Hartford, NY 13413","xcoord":"43.054190","ycoord":"-75.273813"}]

Comment: You can update the question instead of commenting it, to add more details.

Comment: Alright, but can anyone help me

Comment: Is ReturnPlacesJSON.php an URL? If so, I think it should go inside quotes

Comment: Also, wrong types of quotes in `"val.name + ' ' + val.address"`

Comment: Look at the javascript console; this code currently gives the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: ReturnPlacesJSON is not defined`.
Try putting ReturnPlacesJSON.php inside quotes, since it is an URL string, not a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to create h3 and divs, inside the accordion div
What `$('#accordion > h3').each()` and `$('#accordion > div').each()` do is iterating through h3 and divs already inside the accordion, which are none.

What you in fact need to do is iterate through the json - and you do it by calling `$.each(data, ...)` - and then for each item, create a new h3 and a new div with that content.
You create element using jQuery with something like this:

```
$('<h3 />').html(special).appendTo('#accordion');
$('<div />').html(val.name + ' ' + val.address).appendTo('#accordion');
```

I believe the rest of the code must be fine tuned. For instance, I'm not sure that calling `accordion()`, and after that populating the div gives you the desired effect.

Comment: Feel free to give me some feedback, maybe updating your question, and I'll try to help some more.

Comment: updated code, but dont think that is right.  Getting confused on how you are explaining this

Comment: You don't have to enclose that code inside `$.each` calls. The whole block is already inside an `each` call, meaning it's already executed once for each element of the array.
For each element of the array, after you process it extracting the values you need, you only have to output one single `h3` and `div`

Comment: Alright did some changes, but here's the url and what it displays and the one console error shouldn't matter. http://shanewmiller.com/Specials/testing.html

Comment: seems like it iterating correctly, but not putting it into the correct format for the accordion

Comment: It looks like the format is fine. Can you try calling `$('#accordion').accordion()` only after you have added the content, and not before?

Comment: You're not calling accordion() after you populate the div. Remember that $.getJSON is asynchronous, so it happens after document.ready.
You have to call accordion() at the end of the getJSON callback body.

Comment: Thanks dude you were a huge help.  Just needs some CSS work now.